# Office-Js - Excel online - Adding rows to table shows invalid formatting ( outside of the table)

Tags: office-js

I have a table with 5 columns where column cells 2 and 3 set yellow as the background color. When I add/append a new row to the table using `table.row.add(null, [values])` a row is added, however the yellow background (for cells 2, 3) style is extended to an additional row outside of the table. This is a bug from officeJs / excel online.

For a workaround, we are adding a single row like `table.rows.add().values=[]`, but this is not helpful when we deal with more than one rows.

Anyone facing this issue? Please suggest an alternative. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Always be sure to include a working code sample that the steps to replicate the problem with your sample.

Comment: One other thing to add:  For this particular question, it sounds like it's really more of a bug report.  It's totally valid to ask for whether someone knows of a good workaround, but I recommend that you also file the bug (with sample code) at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues